# Content Per User

Tags: joomla-3.x, user-groups

How would one go about creating a user account and adding content for that specific user only.

I want to upload videos that are user specific. I would like to make this as easy as possible, maybe even from the front end.

Comment: which extension you are using to handle videos?
are you using joomla com_content component for this or any other extension

Answer (score 2):

### User content restriction

You can use a plugin called [OSD Content Restriction](http://documentation.form2content.com/f2c-extensions/joomla-content-restriction-plugin). This little plugin will let you define who can see your content based on several parameters. What is shown or hidden can be determined by six different variables, namely the *user group*, the *user*, the *author group*, the *author*, if on the *homepage* or if an article is *featured*.

In your case, the `{user ID}{/user} might be a good option. Here's a couple of examples of usage from the documentation:

```
{user 63} Logged in user 63 (where 63 is the Joomla user id) will see the article content between the plugin syntax. {/user}
{user !59} All logged in users except user 59 will see the article content between the plugin syntax. {/user}
{user 59||84} Only logged in users 59 or 84 will see the article content between the plugin syntax. {/user}
{user !59||!84} All logged in users except users 59 or 84 will see the article content between the plugin syntax. {/user}
```

### Personal user page

Another alternative is a component called [User-Private-Page](http://www.pages-and-items.com/extensions/user-private-page), that lets you set up a unique page for each user, and a default page for users without a unique page.

From the description:

> If you need to display user specific private content. When no private
>   content is set for that user, a default custom message is displayed.
>   When there is content set for that user, the user will need to login
>   to view the user private content. The private content is rendered via
>   the content plugins, so you can use any plugin codes in the user
>   specific content. So you can add video, images, modules and all the
>   goodness of Joomla extensions.

### Conclusion

It really depends on your requirements if any of these solutions works, but it might be a starting point. If you have some PHP knowledge, you can also build your own extension to fit your needs. Also, take a look at [this post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091911/how-to-create-user-specific-content-in-joomla-3-0), you might find usefull information there.